# How to make GET request in this example

Tags: javascript, python, get, request

how do I make GET request as described here: https://noopschallenge.com/challenges/hexbot ? I never did this

I tried writing GET in cmd (windows) but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

use `curl`  to make http request from terminal

it is very powerful tool and you should google it, but a basic GET request looks like :

```
curl --request GET https://noopschallenge.com/challenges/hexbot
```

Comment: add an example of what that would look like.

Comment: it is very powerful tool and you should google it, but a basic GET request looks like : `curl --request GET https://noopschallenge.com/challenges/hexbot`